# How can I add a projection (i.e., epsg=102001) to a Geopandas DF that's in in esri.extra, NOT proj_def.dat file?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, map-projections, proj

I have a Geopandas dataframe with a CRS of epsg:4326 that I would like to transform to a CRC of espg:102001 which has a proj.4 definition as follows:

```
proj4_102001 = '+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'
```

In my /usr/share/proj directory, the projection is located in the esri.extra file but not in the proj_def.dat  file as you can see from the screen shot below:

[Screenshot of 1) the results of the Grep command searching for 102001 and 2)an ls of the /usr/share/proj directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPzvh.png)

According to the [Geopandas documentation](http://geopandas.org/projections.html), the correct ways to define the projection is as follows:

```
world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'})
```

I have tried "world = world.to_crs({'init': 'esri.extra:102001'})" and a number of other variations but none have worked.   I have tried searching the internet for solutions including the [Proj.4 documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/proj.4/gh-pages/proj.pdf), but haven't found any.  Please let me know if you know how to do this.  I am using Ubuntu (Ubuntu-18.04), Python (3.7.1), Geopandas (0.4.0), and  Proj.4 (5.2.0).

Thank you in advance.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to provide the full projection string in the `to_crs` function.

```
world = world.to_crs('+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs')
```